# Error while invoking mobilefirst adapter: Invocation of procedure failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am using:
Mobilefirst platform studio 6.3.0.

I have followed the IBM training modules to create a new mobilefirst adapter.

I am getting an error while trying to invoke a procedure. I have added the required JDBC driver jar file in the server/lib folder. But, I am getting this error.

```
 [ERROR   ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'procedure1' failed. [project pocket]
  Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project /pocket
```

Comment: Which file exactly did you place there? I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar and it is working

Comment: I have tried with mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar. But still, I am facing the same error

Comment: Can you add your adapter XML?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried using the mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar and it is working fine now.

Comment: Great - If you could please either remove the question, or write the above as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar in the server/lib folder as well in the build path of the project.